# What is the relationship of geometric multiplicity and eigenvalues if the rank, r, of a matrix (nxn) is r < n?

Tags: linear-algebra

Say we have an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ where the rank, $r$, of $A$ is $r<n$. What can we say about the geometric multiplicity of each distinct eigenvalue of $A$? Can we say anything about the sum of the geometric multiplicity of the nonzero eigenvalues?

After looking at my notes, I'm seeing that we can assume that there are $n-r$ eigenvalues that are $0$, and that the algebraic multiplicity for the eigenvalue $0$ is also $n-r$. I'm also not quite sure why this is the case.

Comment: $r$ is the sum of the algebraic multiplicities of the nonzero eigenvalues, which means it's an upper bound on the sum of the geometric multiplicities. This is equivalent to the result you stated about the algebraic multiplicity of $0$ and both of these results follow from the Jordan normal form theorem, or from the easier result that matrices over an algebraically closed field can be upper triangularized.

Answer (score 1):

The "direct" consequence of the rank is that the dimension of the nullspace, $n-r$, is the geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalue $0$.

Consequently, we can deduce that the algebraic multiplicity of $0$ is *at least* equal to $n-r$. It follows that the sum of the algebraic multiplicities of the remaining eigenvalues is *at most* equal to $r$ (since the sum of all algebraic multiplicities is $n$).

Note that it is not necessarily the case that the algebraic multiplicity of $0$ is $n-r$. For example, with
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0},
$$
we have $n = 2$, $r=1$, the geometric multiplicity of $0$ is $1$, the algebraic multiplicity of $0$ is $2$, and $A$ has no other eigenvalues.